# Android Material CardView with HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-cardview

i need to show `CardViews` in `HorizontalScrollView` like below tutorial
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/

and here is what i've tryed:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="3sp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/view5"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3sp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="33dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

But i can't use more than two cardview in this layout.(in`HorizontalScrollView`)

should i use another widget for this porpose or what is the problem if i need to show 5 CardView in this Horizontal ScrollView?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) which comes in the android support library and u can see how to add it to your project [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat). It is a better implementation on list view which comes with a Layout manager by which you can configure it to be used as `Horizontal` or `vertical` **Scroll mode**.

```
mRecyclerLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: thank you.So it means, we cant use `HorizontalScrollView` for this porpose? is there any tut or example about this design?

Comment: @AndroidDev here's a [demo](http://www.jayway.com/2014/12/23/android-recyclerview-simple-list/) for using recycler view.